# Clausius paper " On the motive power of heat & on the laws which can be deduced from it for the theory of heat"

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

**My question is simple. Clausius expesses his fundamental proposition as follows:**

"In all cases in which work is produced by the agency of heat, a quantity of heat is consumed which is proportional to the work done"

**the paper can be found here:https://archive.org/details/secondlawthermo01kelvgoog/page/n86**

**Using Carnot's circle for water vapor and defining the following parameters. [page 80]**

$r$: *the quantity of heat which becomes latend when the unit weigh of the liquid evaporates at temperature* $t$ under the coresponding pressure.

$c$: specific heat of the liquid **[water]**

$hdt$: the quantity of heat which must be inparted to a unit weight of the vapor if its temperture is raised from $t$ to $t+dt$.

**he concludes that the heat consumed from a carnot circle is:**

*The heat consumed* = $(\frac{dr}{dt}+c-h)dmdt$

**So far so good, but in sequel he says that** "if we adopt the assumption that the quantity of heat is constant we must replace by $$\frac{dr}{dt}+c-h=0$$

**My question has to do with the last equation. Why he sets zero the whole expression instead of a constant parameter.**

Comment: The Carnot cycle typically describes an irreversible process where higher temperature heat is consumed and lower temperature heat is exhausted back to the surroundings. However in the limit where there is no heat being exchanged with the external environment, the cycle tends towards a reversible adiabatic process instead.